# I use GetProperties() on an enumerated type, the public type is not found and the return value is null

Tags: c#, .net

**This is one of my enumeration types, where some characters are replaced with ***

```
public enum Identity*****
{

    [LabelCssClass(BadgeColorCalss.Default)]
    [Display(Name = "未**")]
    IsNoPo*8 = 1,


    [LabelCssClass(BadgeColorCalss.Info)]
    [Display(Name = "未**")]
    IsPo** = 2,


    [LabelCssClass(BadgeColorCalss.Success)]
    [Display(Name = "已**")]
    Succe** = 3,

    [LabelCssClass(BadgeColorCalss.Danger)]
    [Display(Name = "认证失败")]
    Fail** = 4
}
```

like this enumeration type

```
            var properties = enumType.GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(properties.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------");
            var enumPropertyAttribute = enumType.GetCustomAttribute<ClassPropertyAttribute>();
```

I use the code to get it, but the value I get is empty

How should I modify GetProperties(); to get the correct list of public properties

Comment: An enum doesn't have properties. It has fields. You should call `enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)`.

Comment: Thanks, he's right. One more question, how should I get the value that follows in IsNoPo*8 = 1, that is, the 1 that follows

Comment: You can just cast the enum value to int: `(int)IsNoPo*8`.

Comment: "One more question" - each Stack Overflow post should be about a *single* question, without follow-ups in comments. But as a hint: when you've got all the fields, check their values...